# swagger not preserving sessions

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I am trying to set up a simple login endpoint in swagger:

```
//login.js

'use strict';

function login(req, res){
  const userId = req.swagger.params.user_id.value;
  const user = { 
    _id: userId
  }
  if(req.session.userId){
    return res.json([req.session.userId, 'hello']);
  }

  global.app.db.collection('users').insertOne(user, function(err, b){
    req.session.userId = userId;
    return res.json([req.session]);
  });
}

module.exports = {
  login: login
};
```

It seems the if statement is never true, and the userId is never set permanently (it shows up in just the second return statement after the insert statement).

Not sure what is wrong here. My app.js has the typical express-session setup.

```
//app.js
'use strict';
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const mongoDbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'my_db';


var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
var session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: 'some secret',
  store: new MongoStore({url:mongoDbUrl}),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))

module.exports = app; // for testing
global.app = app;

var config = {
  appRoot: __dirname // required config
};

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  // install middleware
  swaggerExpress.register(app);

  var port = process.env.PORT || 10010;
  app.listen(port);

  if (swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.paths['/hello']) {
    console.log('try this:\ncurl http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/hello?name=Scott');
  }
});

MongoClient.connect(mongoDbUrl, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);
  app.db = db;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was this line:

```
cookie: { secure: true }
```

secure should have been false because I wasn't using https on my local machine.